# PHP - How to toggle text on button using jquery (Advance custom fields) Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, toggle, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advance custom fields where I have two fields of "English" and "Hindi"
in which I have sub fields - Title, Description. So I want to create a toggle button for English and Hindi

[image]

I know the normal toggle of text

```
function fnShowHide( iCol ) {
   $(this).text(function(_, text) { 
    return text === 'Show Name' ? 'Hide Name' : 'Show Name';
  });
}
```

**But I am fetching data of english and hindi, So I want to make a button which will toggle between english and hindi. Is there anyway using jquery ?**

Comment: Use ACF to create language toggle before creating language fields and sub-fields. After having created toggle/ radio button ACF gives you the option to add conditional logic. [See Screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3502821/fc757a1f21fcd54c4513d16c12dcf56f)